# VaryByHeader with OutputCacheAttribute on child actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

With the [OutputCacheAttribute] in ASP.NET MVC 3, you can output cache with a good deal of flexibility. It's useful to leverage the 'VaryByHeader' property to bucket caching by host name. For example:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByHeader = "host")]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return this.View();
}
```

However, on child actions, you cannot apply the 'VaryByHeader'. The framework throws the following exception:

> OutputCacheAttribute for child actions only supports Duration,
>   VaryByCustom, and VaryByParam values. Please do not set CacheProfile,
>   Location, NoStore, SqlDependency, VaryByContentEncoding, or
>   VaryByHeader values for child actions.

My question is, why?

Is the reason why we cannot VaryByHeader in a child action because it would  provide a conflicting variance, since the parent action might have specified a different VaryByHeader value?

If I want to cache child actions differently based upon hostname, what does this mean, and how would I go about it?

Comment: Just curious, do child actions cause another HTTP get?  Maybe the designers of this thought that since there is no _second_ post back there would be no need to cache by different http headers.

Comment: No, child actions are just an abstraction within the same request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`VaryByHeader` affects the actual HTTP Response headers; so you're probably correct that the MVC team blocked this to prevent conflicts with the parent action.

To cache based on hostname, couldn't you use `VaryByCustom`? Something like (disclaimer: haven't tried this at all):

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByCustom = "host")]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return View();
}
```

followed by (in your Global.asax.cs)

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (arg == "host")
    {
        return context.Request.Headers["host"];
    }

    // whatever you have already, or just String.Empty
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Caching based on hostname is already possible just by using VaryByHeader. In a 2 hostname scenario, for example, the child action will be cached twice, once for host A, and once for host B. You wouldn't need to use VaryByCustom. (Though your method would indeed work too, and is probably very similar to the implementation of VaryByHeader).

Comment: Of course, but since you can't use `VaryByHeader` in your ChildAction... :)